# don't work onClick of view that is in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I have a recyclerView for chat! i want record voice and play it in chat ...
for this i have a layout for play and pause voice ...i need voice position in recyclerview to play it.

I have tried two methods:
1-  msgRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener 
but in this way i can't control play and pause voice with one button 
2- onClick for play button and onClick for pause button 
in this way i don't have voice position in recyclerView

```
    pos=msgRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
```

stops application

```
msgRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), msgRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {


                    List<Messages> messages = new DB_Helper(getApplicationContext()).getListOfMessages("MsgPos = " + position + " and DriverID = " + 2 + " and OperatorID = " + id);
                    String locPath = messages.get(0).getLocalPath();
                    int msgType = messages.get(0).getMsgType();
                    if (msgType == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("picture", messages.get(0).getImage());
                        startActivity(intent);


                    } else if (msgType == 2) {
                        //video
                        //String VideoUri = String.valueOf(d.getDuration());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Video", locPath);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else if (msgType == 3) {

                        pos=position;


                }

                @Override
                public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    // do whatever
                }
            })
    );




public void playVoice(View view)
    {
        if(mediaPlayer!=null)
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        List<Messages> messages = new DB_Helper(getApplicationContext()).getListOfMessages("MsgPos = " + pos + " and DriverID = " + 2 + " and OperatorID = " + id);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(messages.get(0).getLocalPath()));
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }



 public void pauseVoice(View view)
    {
     //   pos=msgRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
        List<Messages> messages = new DB_Helper(getApplicationContext()).getListOfMessages("MsgPos = " + pos + " and DriverID = " + 2 + " and OperatorID = " + id);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(messages.get(0).getLocalPath()));
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
```

In this mode, the click function does not work..

Please help me to play and stop voice in chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try onclick method in your adapter. Like this;

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //your code
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should give activity/fragment context in adapter constructor. Like this `YourAdapter(Context context, int yourLayout, ArrayList<Object> yourList)`